# Three.AreaLight with Three.Points Highlight creates lighting / reflection artefacts on object

Tags: javascript, 3d, three.js, particle-system

[image: Comparison]I created a simple Particle System with a texture as THREE.PointsMaterial. It is a white round dot 16x16px png with transparency. The Particles are displayed as expected. In the scene I also have a test object loaded with `THREE.JSONLoader()`and a basic material `material.color.setHex( 0xFF0000 )` and a `THREE.RectAreaLight`.

As soon as I add the Particle System I have huge white artefacts like a  reflection or highlight on the testobject.

When I remove the AreaLight an different light reflection is gone. So somehow adding the Particlesystem changes the reflection / lighting of the the Testobject. Why does the addition of the particle system change the material of an independent object?

Many thanks for any help

```
var particleGeometry = new THREE.Geometry();
    var textureLoader = new THREE.TextureLoader();
    var sprite1 = textureLoader.load(  '/assets/js/libs/app/textures/particle.png' );

    for ( var i = 0; i < 1000; i ++ ) {

        var particle = new THREE.Vector3();
        particle.x = THREE.Math.randFloat( -200, 200 );
        particle.y = THREE.Math.randFloat( -200, 200 );
        particle.z = THREE.Math.randFloat( -200, 200 );

        particleGeometry.vertices.push( particle );

    }

    var particleMaterial = new THREE.PointsMaterial( { size: 1.0, map: sprite1, blending: THREE.AdditiveBlending, depthTest: true, transparent : true } );
    particleSystem = new THREE.Points( particleGeometry, particleMaterial );

    scene.add( particleSystem );
```

Comment: You could add a picture of that "reflection-like" effect.

Comment: Added to the post. Also there is an THREE.RectAreaLight in the scene which I forgot to mention in the original post

Comment: Did you find solution to this?